# How to save console.log messages from someone else's website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I was able to save the console messages from someone else's website by using chrome.exe --enable-logging --v=1 to a local file. However, I ran into the issue of the text file saving objects as [object Object]. I want the objects to be in JSON. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Are you sure you want the objects as JSON? Remember, JSON doesn't save things like functions

Comment: yes, i'm not interested in the functions it has data I'm trying to work with.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I have the same problem - I'm writing a log file 
 ("chrome_debug.log" with the target set as `chrome.exe --enable-logging --v=1`), and I want to include the actual data, instead of just "[object Object]" as you also had.

Comment: I gave up on that, I looked at the website again and found out that data I was looking for was under the network/payload. I haven't tried figuring out how to save this data though.